# Select All records using IN Clause when no records available inside IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to query a table based on comma separated values. If values are present, I need to use. If its empty I need to select all

```
DECLARE @UserIdList VARCHAR(500) = '150, 112' // Not working when its ''

DECLARE @Users TABLE (UserId INT);

WITH UserCSVtoTable AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(t.val, ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM 
        (SELECT @UserIdList) AS t(val)
)
INSERT INTO @Users (UserId)
    SELECT m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)') AS UserId
    FROM UserCSVtoTable
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
```

Query

```
SELECT UserId, Email
FROM Users
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM @Users)
```

It works only when I send values. If I send '' its not taking all records.

How to get all records when no records available in the `@Users` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT UserId, Email
From Users
Where UserId IN (Select UserId from @Users)
  OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Users);
```

Assuming that `UserId` is defined as `NOT NULL` then both conditions are mutually exclusive.